# How to view all Versions of documents in a view

Tags: view, version, ootb

I want to create a view that will show me all versions of specific document OOTB. Is that possible? as per my knowledge, we can only see latest versions of document in a view.

Answer (score 1):

The view is used to show items. So even if there may be numerous versions associated with an item, the view will still show one item only and not each version of an item.

Comment: but can I see specific version of particular item using view?

Comment: You can filter by Version number. But that will give the version which is latest. So, if you have 2 documents one with version 3.0 and other with version 5.0 and you filter by version number equal to 3.0. You will see first document. But the view will present the latest information.

Comment: Moreover, you won't see version 3 of second document in above example that I gave in comment.

Comment: Just thought you may be interested in my codeplex project https://exportversionhistory.codeplex.com/. This exports version history into Excel.

Comment: thanks .i don't want to use coding here.requirement is to see all original documents in view.